# Cannot backup Andrioid Chrome data with adb

Tags: adb, samsung-galaxy-s-2

I've connected my Samsung Galaxy S2 to my computer via USB debugging and run:

`adb backup -noapk com.android.chrome`

The result file backup.ab has only 41 bytes.

What's wrong?